# Panels vs template performance

Tags: theming, panels

Sorry for rather newbie question. I am reading an Panel CookBook and how to create different layouts for homepage and other landpages. Apparently it is possible to achieve the same result with Panels models and template sub-theming and overriding. So my questions are:
1. When to use one of the above methods?
2. Performance issues Panels vs Theme overriding?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think the thing to keep in mind here is how the site is going to be used.  If users are not going to log into it, it *almost* doesn't matter in terms of performance because you use Boost.

http://drupal.org/project/boost

You can also use caching features in panels.  I've never really noted a large hit for using panels on a website, as long as the layout is reasonable and the site does not have an excessive amount of modules on it.  Panels exposes *a lot* of functionality, and you can pry it out of my cold dead hands.

If you've not used Boost before, do yourself a favor and commit to doing so!

NOTE: In your other question you referenced D7.  Boost may not be ready for D7 just yet but you should keep it in mind.

Comment: Since I am newbie it is first time hearing about Boost. About D7 this is another question which bother me right now .... I am reading a lot that there are not very much modules ported there yet. So, should I first use panels (to speed up development) and if performance decrease go for subthemeing?

Comment: We always use a mix of features because panels adds so much functionality.  I'd suggest fooling around with panels a bit and setting up Boost.  If you have performance concerns, literally your first step is to look at Boost.